# Messed up bluetooth configuration, cannot see or connect to bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo

After a glitch, I tried reinstalling my bluetooth packages (Like attempting to uninstall bluetooth in device manager in Windows) and `hcitool scan` brings up the error:

```
Device is not available: No such device"
```

After `"sudo service bluetooth restart` I get:

```
Job for bluetooth.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status bluetooth.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-02-01 14:59:53 MST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 7249 ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/chmod o+rw /var/run/sdp (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 7248 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7248 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "Quitting"

Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 bluetoothd[7248]: Bluetooth daemon 5.35
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 systemd[7249]: bluetooth.service: Failed ...
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Control p...3
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 bluetoothd[7248]: Starting SDP server
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 bluetoothd[7248]: Terminating
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 bluetoothd[7248]: Stopping SDP server
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth se....
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Unit ente....
Feb 01 14:59:53 will-Lenovo-Edge-15 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed wi....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

How do I fix this? (Ubuntu 15 with Gnome shell, on a Lenovo Edge 15)

Comment: Which packages you tried to re-install?

Comment: bluez, bluez-tools and blueman. When I reinstalled them there were some configuration errors that prevent the packages from running.

Comment: @Pilot6 any recommendations here?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/748592 helped me. Just simple reinstal with apt

Answer (score 0):

/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service and changing this line

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` to this

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat`

and then restarting Bluetooth like this

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

and you'll also have to change permissions on /var/run/sdp

`sudo chmod 777 /var/run/sdp`